# Change vector value based on value in same vector

Tags: r, vector

This is probably a similar question to other posted before, but I couldn't find an exact match (please direct me to it if it's already on here).

Anyway, I have a matrix with 19 columns and ~5,000 rows. Each row contains one value between 0.0 and 1 in increments of .1 (so, 0.0, 0.1,0.2...1.0) like thus:

```
0 0.6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0.9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So the vectors go from 1 to 0.1 before starting over again at 1 and shifted over to the next column. I'd like a function that basically goes from row to row, looks to see if there is a numeric value and then puts 1 minus that value in the next place in the vector. Effectively like this:

```
0 0.6 0.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0.4 0.6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0.9 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0.8 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've tried a few things with "apply" or just base recoding but the trick is getting it to run through all ~5,000 rows. Maybe I should approach it by going through the columns?

Comment: You can working the columns with `ifelse`, check the previous column value and change current column when condition match. `ifelse` is vectorized so every column operation is fast. You need a for loop to start from the rightmost column to left.

Comment: another method is to calculate all the index of cells to be changed, put them into a vector, and calculate all the values to be updated in same order, put into another vector, then update them by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think value and index separately. Indexing in R could be very powerful.

```
# simulate data. smaller size for simplification
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 200, ncol = 12)
r_indice <- 1:200
c_indice <- rep(2:11, each = 10)
m[cbind(r_indice, c_indice)] <- rep(seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), 10)

# find non-zero value indice
value_indice <- which(m !=0, arr.ind = T)
new_value_indice <- value_indice
new_value_indice[, 2] <- new_value_indice[, 2] + 1
m[new_value_indice] <- 1 - m[value_indice]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I hadn't considered indexing the entire matrix all at once. The only change I had to make was to add a dummy column to the end of my matrix to accommodate for the "+1" shift in the column index reference, otherwise I got a "subscript out of bounds" error. I can simply drop that column now without impacting the rest of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that combines simple matrix multiplication and matrix indexing. First, we create a 19 x 20 matrix with pairs of 1 and -1 in each row.

```
mat <- diag(20)
mat[row(mat) - col(mat) == -1]  <- -1
mat <- mat[-20, ]
```

`mat` looks like:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] ...
# [1,]    1   -1    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1   -1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1   -1    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1   -1    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    1   -1
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
# ...
```

Suppose your original matrix is `x`.  Then we multiply `x` and `mat`:

```
y <- x %*% mat
```

so that we get back the same numbers as `x`, but also the negative of those numbers in the adjacent column:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0  0.6 -0.6  0.0    0    0
[2,]    0  0.5 -0.5  0.0    0    0
[3,]    0  0.4 -0.4  0.0    0    0
[4,]    0  0.0  1.0 -1.0    0    0
[5,]    0  0.0  0.9 -0.9    0    0
[6,]    0  0.0  0.8 -0.8    0    0
```

Finally, add 1 to all the negative numbers:

```
y[y < 0] <- (y + 1)[y < 0]
y[1:6, 1:6]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0  0.6  0.4  0.0    0    0
# [2,]    0  0.5  0.5  0.0    0    0
# [3,]    0  0.4  0.6  0.0    0    0
# [4,]    0  0.0  1.0  0.0    0    0
# [5,]    0  0.0  0.9  0.1    0    0
# [6,]    0  0.0  0.8  0.2    0    0
```