# Matlab: change vector values based on if-else condition on the same vector

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vector

I have a threshold requirement and would like to round values of a vector to 0 or 1. I don't need to save the old values of the vector

I saw, in the link below, that I could use the following to change the all values of 0 in the `s` vector to -1 with `s( s==0 )=-1`; or in general `vector(if condition) = desiredValue`.

This is better than using a for loop and having an enclosed if condition. What if I would like to include another condition: to change all values greater than 0.8 to 1? Would I have to add another line of code:`s( s>=0.8 )=1`; or is there a way of checking the two conditions by traversing the vector just once? I only know of using a for loop with an enclosed if-else condition but would like a shorter version if one exists.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158413

The only related link I found was for R but I am not working with it: [Change vector value based on value in same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670638/change-vector-value-based-on-value-in-same-vector)

Comment: Google "logical indexing." In Matlab it is generally faster than using for-loops.

Comment: You can check the two conditions at once using a pipe `|` for "or", or using an ampersand `&` for "and". You can't assign different values to each condition in the same way though. Doing this in two lines is still reasonably efficient, and extremely efficient compared to looping. See this Mathworks blog: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab allows so-called logical indexing, which is really efficient. To understand what

```
s(s>0.8) = 1;
```

does, you can check it with two steps:

```
ind = s>0.8;
```

Here *ind* is a logical array with the same size as *s*, and has true (1) at locations where s is greater than 0.8, and false (0) otherwise.

```
s(ind) = 1;
```

will assign *s* to 1 at locations where *ind* is true, while not touching those where *ind* is false.

To make this easy to understand, you can do this:

```
ind = find(ind);
```

This will return those indices for s>0.8. Then you do

```
s(ind) = 1;
```

The logical indexing allows you to skip *find*, which makes the code simpler and much faster.

To change to different values (-1 and 1 in your example), you need two command for the assignment.